# In JavaScript how do I create a list of differences of array elements elegantly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have a list of numbers, say `numbers = [3,7,9,10]` and I want to have a list
containing the differences between neighbor elements - which has to have one 
less element - in the given case  `diffs = [4,2,1]`

Of course I could create a new list go through the input list and compile my
result manually.

I'm looking for an elegant/functional (not to say pythonic) way to do this.
In Python you would write `[j-i for i, j in zip(t[:-1], t[1:])]` or use `numpy`
for this.

Is there a `reduce()`/list comprehension approach in JavaScript, too?

Comment: Have you considered using a library like `lodash`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could slice and map the difference.

```js
var numbers = [3, 7, 9, 10],
    result = numbers.slice(1).map((v, i) => v - numbers[i]);

console.log(result);
```

A reversed approach, with a later slicing.

```js
var numbers = [3, 7, 9, 10],
    result = numbers.map((b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => b - a).slice(1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using `reduce` method

```js
const numbers = [3, 7, 9, 10]
const res = numbers.reduce((r, e, i, a) => i ? r.concat(e - a[i - 1]) : r, []);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also pop after map:

```js
var numbers = [3, 7, 9, 10],
result = numbers.map((v, i) => numbers[i+1]-v);
result.pop()

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` and `slice`

```js
const numbers = [3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13];


const res = numbers.map((num, index) => numbers[index + 1] - num).slice(0, -1);



console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring assignment and recursion -

```js
const diff = ([ a, b, ...more ]) =>
  b === undefined
    ? []
    : [ b - a, ...diff ([ b, ...more ]) ]
    
 
console .log (diff ([ 3, 7, 9, 10 ]))
// [ 4, 2, 1 ]

console .log (diff ([ 3 ]))
// []

console .log (diff ([]))
// []
```

Or skip some intermediate values by using an index -

```js
const diff = (a = [], i = 1) =>
  i >= a.length
    ? []
    : [ a[i] - a[i - 1], ...diff (a, i + 1) ]
    
console .log (diff ([ 3, 7, 9, 10 ]))
// [ 4, 2, 1 ]

console .log (diff ([ 3 ]))
// []

console .log (diff ([]))
// []
```

If needed, make it stack-safe using `loop` and `recur`. This one runs really fast, too -

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })
  
const loop = f =>
{ let r = f ()
  while (r && r.recur === recur)
    r = f (...r.values)
  return r
}

const push = (a = [], v) =>
  ( a .push (v)
  , a
  )
  
const diff = (a = []) =>
  loop
    ( ( i = 1
      , r = []
      ) =>
        i >= a.length
          ? r
          : recur
              ( i + 1
              , push (r, a[i] - a[i - 1])
              )
    )
    
console .log (diff ([ 3, 7, 9, 10 ]))
// [ 4, 2, 1 ]

console .log (diff ([ 3 ]))
// []

console .log (diff ([]))
// []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice (0 as a start, -1 to skip the last item) and map so to generate the differences between an element and its successor in the sequence:

```js
    const items = [3,7,9,10];
    console.log(items.slice(0,-1).map((e,i)=>items[i+1]-e))
```